# Solving for length of AB

Tags: geometry, triangles

From the diagram below, if DB = 2, BC = 8 and $\angle$ABC = $\angle$ACB = $\angle$CED = $\angle$CDE, determine the length of AB.

[image]

I know concepts of similar triangles are needed to solved this question. Here's what I have gathered so far ...

My attempt:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From $CE/6=8/CE$ one gets $CE=\sqrt{48}$ and from the second proportion one can then compute $AB$.